# Symfony 3.4 - update config in prod mode is not working

Tags: symfony, locale, language-translation

I have a customer's website developed with Symfony 3.4 framework. In the config.yml the default locale is fr and the website use this config to set the language. But at the begining, the default locale is en and the website is in english. I set it in fr and clear cache for env prod. But the website and default locale still in en...

How to refresh config on prod mode to update changes on the website?

Answer (score 0):

- First, check that the default locale is fr in the `config.yml` file
- Then, make sure that you have a French translation file, usually `app/Resources/translations/messages.fr.yml`, and that it contains French translations
- Finally, make sure that the translations are used in your twig template files, eg. that you use:

  ```
  {{ 'translation_code'|trans }}
  ```

Clear and warm-up the cache, and it should work.